# Using Ajax=>WebService to save multiple input field values

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am working on ASP.Net webforms i have a user control with multiple input fields around 50-60 fields. The data from these fields is being saved and loaded on a save button click right now which takes alot of time.

I wanted to know if I save the data from these input fields using ajax calling a webservice on the focusout or blur event of the input field! is that a better alternative? And will it cause problems if multiple users are calling this web service so many times!! Any other solutions to my problem will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a good method, as people might end up sending a lot of blank data and this is just a waste of bandwidth. Remember, it will take almost equally long for sending data from all text fields, when compared with sending from one text field. Validation of the data could also be a problem and there will end up being a lot of code redundancies, regarding the extra validation and ajax calls being made. On the other hand, if you use an intermediate server, it can be a lot more responsive, assuming the ping between the intermediate and the user is low and the ping between the intermediate and the back-end server is also low and controlled by you.

Other than that, I don't know of any better method than sending all the data on a form submit.